# Bind collection to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have this combobox

```
<ComboBox  Height="30" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="5 3 5 3" Width="170" ItemsSource="{Binding WonderList}" SelectedValuePath="selectedWonder">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path}" Height="20"></Image>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource LabelComboItem}"></Label>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

where I want to show items as an image plus a text.

This is the business class for the objects in the item list

```
public class Wonder: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private string path;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #region properties, getters and setters
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Path { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public Wonder(string name, string path)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

and the code behind of the window

```
public class Window1 {
    public List<Wonder> WonderList;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WonderList = new List<Wonder>();
        WonderList.Add(new Wonder("Alexandria", "Resources/Images/Scans/Wonders/Alexandria.jpg"));
        WonderList.Add(new Wonder("Babylon", "Resources/Images/Scans/Wonders/Babylon.jpg"));
    }
}
```

I´m pretty new to this xaml "magic" and guess I dont understand correctly how the data binding works, I think that with `ItemsSource="{Binding WonderList}"` it should take the collection with that name (from the code behind) and show their Name and Path, but it shows an empty list.

If I do `Combo1.ItemsSource = WonderList;` in the code behind (I prefer to use the xaml and avoid the code behind), it shows two blank slots but still don´t know how to show the items.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bind like this `ItemsSource="{Binding WonderList}"` you have to set the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) first.

```
public Window1()
{
    ...
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Then Binding will find the WonderList in Window1 but only if it is a property too.

```
public List<Wonder> WonderList { get; private set; }
```

Next: It is useless to bind to property Name if you assign your value to private field name. Replace your constructor with

```
public Wonder(string name, string path)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Path = path;
}
```

Next: Your auto properties (`{ get; set; }`) will not notify for changes. For this you have to call `OnPropertyChanged` in setter. e.g.

```
public String Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        if (name == value) return;
        name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

Same thing for WonderList. If you create the List to late in constructor it could be all bindings are already resolved and you see nothing.

And finally use [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) if you want to notify not for a new list but a new added item in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing the correct way. Simply saying, you should have a Wonders class holding an ObservableCollection property, which is bound to ComboBox's ItemsSource. You should read MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx