# Selecting ComboBox item programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp

I bind my ComboBox with static way.

when I set the string value which I get from item object (from service method), for example item.AssignmentType="xyz" I want to make it selectable in combobox.
I tried below, but not working

```
<ComboBoxItem Content="abc"/>
<ComboBoxItem Content="xyz"/>
<ComboBoxItem Content="pqrs"/>

string assignmenttype = item.AssignmentType.ToString();
AssignmentTypeCombobox.SelectedIndex =
AssignmentTypeCombobox.Items.IndexOf(assignmenttype);
```

Comment: [Combobox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just try `AssignmentTypeCombobox.Text = "xyz"`

Comment: but, "Text"  property not exist for UWP combobox

Comment: check [UWP Combobox binding to SelectedItem property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821672/uwp-combobox-binding-to-selecteditem-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind everything senseful to a ComboBox. I would recommend some kind of collection (ObservableCollection). You need to set the DataContext to this collection and you´re ready to go. For further details check this:
[Bind collection to combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265427/bind-collection-to-combobox)